# mySQL error with Fulltext Search(match BOOLEAN), then mysqli_fetch_array()

Tags: full-text-search, boolean, match

I have problem with Fulltext Search (php,mySQLi)

With sql LIKE it works and no errors(not FULLtextSEARCH). But when i run it with MATCH it doesnt work and wamp returns  `Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\myweb1`

```
....
include 'connect_db.php';


$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM $cat 
                      WHERE title 
                      LIKE '%YTE BLADE%' 
                      OR description LIKE '%predam%' 
                      OR locality LIKE '%predam%' ");      //with this it works but its not FULLtext search

$result = mysqli_query($con, "  SELECT * FROM $cat 
                        WHERE 
                        MATCH (title,description,locality)
                        AGAINST ('autobus' IN BOOLEAN MODE);");


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){....then i display data
```

Can you help?

Comment: Your query has failed. Check the value of `mysqli_error($con)` after the query for an error code. It's probably `1064 - syntax error`. If it is, check the syntax of your query thoroughly.

Comment: I add this: `or die("Error: ".mysqli_error($con));` after query and i have `Error: Can't find FULLTEXT index matching the column list`

Answer (score 0):

I solve that. Problem was that muss be set in phpMyAdmin Storage Engine from InnoDB to MyISAM then it works.
Final Fulltext search code was:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT *,
                    MATCH(title, description, locality) AGAINST('$keyword') AS score
                    FROM $cat
                    WHERE MATCH(title, description, locality) AGAINST('$keyword')
                    ORDER BY score DESC, create_date DESC;");
```

Thanks